# Difference between "&lt" and "<"

Tags: javascript, operators

I saw people use some special characters like '&lt' instead of '<' in an enterprise project and write codes like this:

```
if (someting.length &lt; 10000)
```

Is there any special reason for that?

Comment: The difference is that `<` is a javascript operator, while `&lt;` is not

Comment: That's not going to work unless it gets parsed at some point. It looks like someone is html encoding your html output and accidentally also encoding your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;` is `<` escaped (in a form of XML entity), so the code you posted is not valid, unless it's been encoded.

After decoding, code would look like:

```
if (someting.length < 10000)
```

so it makes sense now.

You can look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for a full list of XML/HTML entities.

**Edit:** as per comment by @Dan Goodspeed, note that trailing `;` is mandatory.

Comment: And I would like to emphasize - don't forget the ";" at the end of the encoded entity.

Answer (score 0):

Is the code per-chance in an XML file, or similar?

Obviously in XML files, the angular parenthesis have a special meaning - they create tags which start / end elements, for example:

```
<html></html>
```

Thus, if you use angular parenthesis as part of the text inside an element, this can confuse certain XML interpreters, for example:

```
<html>This is an angular parenthesis for less-than < </html>
```

To avoid the confusion that the parenthesis in the text block is not the start of a new element, it's best to "escape" it:

```
<html>This is an angular parenthesis for less-than &lt; </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<`, `>`, `&` etc are used in XML syntax. if you want use these in our text, to avoid confusion to parser we use `&lt;` for `<`, `&gt;` for `>`, `&amp;` for `&` etc.

These are called XMl entity.

HTML is another markup language that supports entities.